# jQuery on click not working after ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

My Website is based on WordPress and Pages are loaded via ajax on click menu. 
MY Menu's are vertical with a fixed panel type sidebar. 
When a menu icon is clicked on the website, the Menu Panel will show, and hide after clicking a link/menu.

My problem is, after clicking a menu/link from the panel, the page loads via ajax, and after loading the page, the menu button doesn't work and the panel doesn't open any more. I already tried:

> jQuery(document).on('click', '#menu', function(){ //Your code here});

**Here is my JS code. Please check and tell me what I'm doing wrong here?**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Dropdown Menu Code for vertical menu panel
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery("li.menu-item-has-children ul").hide();
    });
    jQuery(document).on("click", "li.menu-item-has-children a", function() {
        jQuery(this).next("ul").toggle();
    });
    // This jQuery code For Automaticly Hide Panel after onclick a link
    jQuery(document).on('click','li.menu-item a', function(){
        var href = jQuery(this).attr('href');
        // If link has no value then don't jQuery will don't tigger
        if (href === undefined || jQuery.trim(href) === '') {
            //event.preventDefault();
            console.log('No href value');
        }else{
            jQuery('section.side_menu').removeClass('open-menu');
            jQuery('#side_menu_button_links').removeClass('open');
        }
    });
    // Menu button on click panel will open/close
    jQuery(document).on('click','#side_menu_button_links', function(){
        if(jQuery(this).hasClass('open')){
            jQuery(this).removeClass('open');
            jQuery('section.side_menu').removeClass('open-menu');
        }else{
            jQuery(this).addClass('open');
            jQuery('section.side_menu').addClass('open-menu');
        }
    });
    //Close Menu on click Panel X icon.
    jQuery(document).on('click','a.close_my_menu', function(){
        jQuery('section.side_menu').removeClass('open-menu');
        jQuery('#side_menu_button_links').removeClass('open');
    });
</script>
```

Here is the HTML step by Step

** Menu Button code. On click this open Panel **

```
<div class="header_inner_right">
    <div class="side_menu_button_wrapper right">
        <div class="side_menu_button" style="height: 85px;">

            <span class="side_menu_button_text">Menu </span>
            <a id="side_menu_button_links" class="side_menu_button_links large open" href="javascript:void(0)">
                <span aria-hidden="true" class="qode_icon_font_elegant icon_menu "></span> </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**The Panel HTML Code**

```
<section class="side_menu right light open-menu" style="overflow-y: hidden; outline: none;" tabindex="5000">
    <div class="side_menu_title">
        <h5>MENU</h5>
    </div>
    <a href="#" target="_self" class="close_my_menu"></a>
    <div id="nav_menu-5" class="widget widget_nav_menu posts_holder">
        <div class="menu-main_menu-container">
            <ul id="menu-main_menu" class="menu">
                <li id="menu-item-15350" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item page-item-14869 current_page_item menu-item-15350"><a href="http://website.com/">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-15369" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-15369"><a>About Us</a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu" style="display: block;">
                        <li id="menu-item-15487" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-15487"><a href="http://website.com/who-we-are/">Who We Are</a>
                        </li>
                        <li id="menu-item-15445" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-15445"><a href="http://website.com/our-tem">Our Team</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-15372" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-15372"><a href="http://website.com/per-coverages">Personal Coverages</a>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-15370" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-15370"><a href="http://website.com/com-coverages">Commercial Coverages</a>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-15373" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-15373"><a href="http://website.com/benefits">Group Benefits</a>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-15357" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-15357"><a href="http://website.com/quote">Get a Quote</a>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-15371" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-15371"><a href="http://website.com/contact">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: any errors in console?

Comment: no error :( Its trigger ! I use this *console.log('Menu work');* too. its its show that its trigger!

Comment: Please share the HTML as well, so as to understand the issue better.

Comment: You don't have any `ajax` code here. Where is it?

Comment: Please post your ajax code

Comment: Still there's no AJAX here

Comment: The ajax code comes with themes and minified. Here is the code: https://pastebin.com/XTAxab6V  is there any way to without edit ajax code work the button? currently button work only 1st time.

Comment: Okay, here is one thing maybe help you that, on ajax success its remove all code from the current html body and write its response data including all js code, all html , all css files.

Comment: please post unminified code

Comment: Sorry sir, I don't have unminified code. the minified version of code comes with Wordpress Themes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it using different **on click jquery** replace of **if/else** method. Here is my current jquery codes:

**And jQuery is:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery("li.menu-item-has-children ul").hide();
    });
    jQuery(document).on("click", "li.menu-item-has-children a", function() {
        jQuery(this).next("ul").toggle();
    });
    jQuery(document).on('click','li.menu-item a', function(){
        var href = jQuery(this).attr('href');
        if (href === undefined || jQuery.trim(href) === '') {
            //event.preventDefault();
            console.log('No href value');
        }else{
            jQuery('section.side_menu').removeClass('open-menu');
            jQuery('#side_menu_button_links').removeClass('open').addClass('close');
        }
    });

    // If menu Open
    jQuery(document).on('click','a.side_menu_button_links.large.open', function(e){

        jQuery(this).removeClass('open').addClass('close');
        jQuery('section.side_menu').removeClass('open-menu');

    });
    // If Menu Close
    jQuery(document).on('click','a.side_menu_button_links.large.close', function(e){

        jQuery(this).removeClass('close').addClass('open');
        jQuery('section.side_menu').addClass('open-menu');

    });

    jQuery(document).on('click','a.close_my_menu', function(){
        jQuery('section.side_menu').removeClass('open-menu');
        jQuery('#side_menu_button_links').removeClass('open').addClass('close');
    });
</script>
```

I don't know what's wrong with if / else code. After ajax request if+else work at a time. I mean 1st menu was open & then close. I track this using `console.log();`